# Joining tables in sql and obtain the data as per the query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

I have three tables( movie,actor,casting). I want to know the actors name for the id obtained from this query.

```
select id from movie where title ='Casablanca';
```

My tables:

```
Movie   | Actor | casting
_______  ________   _______

Movieid   Actorid   Movieid
title     name      Actorid
yr        ord
director        
budget      
gross
```

Comment: If you expect any replies, make your question more informative. Provide the table structures. Use formatting. Show what you have tried  and what problems you faced while trying.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM movie m
INNER JOIN casting c
  ON m.id = c.movieid
INNER JOIN actor a
  ON c.actorid = a.id
WHERE m.title = 'Casablanca';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name 
FROM actor a 
INNER JOIN casting c 
        ON a.id = c.actorid
INNER JOIN movie m 
        ON c.movieid = m.id
WHERE m.title ='Casablanca';
```